# How do I use the ngCordova sqlite service and the Cordova-SQLitePlugin with Ionic Framework?

Tags: angularjs, sqlite, cordova, ionic-framework

I have been trying to incorperate sqlite into a simple Ionic app and this is the process I have been following:

```
 ionic start myApp sidemenu
```

Then I install the sqlite plugin:

```
ionic plugin add https://github.com/brodysoft/Cordova-SQLitePlugin
```

and ngCordova

```
bower install ngCordova
```

this gave me the following options:
Unable to find a suitable version for angular, please choose one:
    1) angular#1.2.0 which resolved to 1.2.0 and is required by ngCordova#0.1.4-alpha 
    2) angular#>= 1.0.8 which resolved to 1.2.0 and is required by angular-ui-router#0.2.10 
    3) angular#1.2.25 which resolved to 1.2.25 and is required by angular-animate#1.2.25, angular-sanitize#1.2.25 
    4) angular#~1.2.17 which resolved to 1.2.25 and is required by ionic#1.0.0-beta.13Prefix the choice with ! to persist it to bower.json

I picked option 3)
 and I included the scripts in the file as follows:

```
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js"></script>
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
```

I then added a controller to the search view:

```
.controller('SearchCtrl', function ($scope, $cordovaSQLite){
  console.log('Test');
   var db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({ name: "my.db" });

        // for opening a background db:
        var db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({ name: "my.db", bgType: 1 });

        $scope.execute = function() {
          console.log('Test');
          var query = "INSERT INTO test_table (data, data_num) VALUES (?,?)";
          $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, ["test", 100]).then(function(res) {
            console.log("insertId: " + res.insertId);
          }, function (err) {
            console.error(err);
          });
     };
})
```

This caused the error:

```
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'openDatabase' of undefined
>     at Object.openDB  (http://localhost:8100/lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js:2467:36)
```

Next I tried manually including the SQLitePlugin.js by:
copying from ***plugins/com.brodysoft.sqlitePlugin/www*** to main ***www/*** and adding it to the index.html page

I tried including before everything:

```
 <script src="SQLitePlugin.js"></script>
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js"></script>
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
```

I get Error **ReferenceError: cordova is not defined**
so I then tried including it after the cordova.js script but still get the same error

would really appreciate the help
in case it is relevant, these are the current versions of Cordova and ionic I am using:

```
ionic --version  1.2.5
cordova --version 3.5.0-0.2.7
```

and this is the generated bower.json

```
{
  "name": "myApp",
  "private": "true",
  "devDependencies": {
    "ionic": "driftyco/ionic-bower#1.0.0-beta.13"
  }
}
```

and my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "myApp: An Ionic project",
  "dependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.5.6",
    "gulp-sass": "^0.7.1",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp-minify-css": "^0.3.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "bower": "^1.3.3",
    "gulp-util": "^2.2.14",
    "shelljs": "^0.3.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If someone still got an error when trying to run it in a browser, try this one:

```
if (window.cordova) {
      db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({ name: "my.db" }); //device
    }else{
      db = window.openDatabase("my.db", '1', 'my', 1024 * 1024 * 100); // browser
    }
```

Comment: That is what the doctor ordered, very grateful!

Comment: About the last parameter that represent the database size. What does `1024 * 1024 * 100` mean?

Answer (score 8):

So Turns out that it is because Cordova is platform specific and doesn't work when you run `ionic serve`

I was able to run the same code on an android device with out issue when I built and deployed.

### Update

you can replace the cordova plugin with window to use the websql databases
so instead of `sqlitePlugin.openDatabase()` you can use `window.openDatabase()`

Comment: Odd. WebSQL runs natively in Chrome - you should have been able to test that in the desktop.

Comment: You can use `window.openDatabase` with `ionic serve` and `window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase` for platforms.

Comment: Thanks I actually only figured that out myself the other day, I will update my answer to show this

Comment: do you actually replace in the plugin file?? shouldn't this be agnostic to work with both browser/device

Comment: no just use window instead of the plugin for testing on the desktop so for example in my controller I would replace `var db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({ name: "my.db" });` with `var db = window.openDB({ name: "my.db" });`

Comment: "Uncaught TypeError: window.openDB is not a function"

Comment: @JasonG sorry its `window.openDatabase()`

Answer (score 1):

In Ionic 2, I am using the following code.

```
constructor(platform: Platform) {
platform.ready().then(() => {



  if(platform.is("cordova")){
    //USE Device
  }
  else {
    //USE Browser
  }



  StatusBar.styleDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

*For later Ionic versions (Ionic 2+)*:

**The best way to handle persistent storage with Ionic is using [ionic-storage](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-storage).**

Ionic Storage is a package created and maintained by the ionic team to abstract development from the specifics of each browser or platform and automatically use the best storage solution available.

## 1. Installing Dependencies

In your case for SQLite you need to first install the dependencies for both Angular and Cordova:

`npm install @ionic/storage --save`

and

`cordova plugin add cordova-sqlite-storage --save`

Then edit your NgModule declaration in `src/app/app.module.ts` to add `IonicStorageModule` as an import:

```js
import { IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [...],
  imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot({
      name: '__mydb',
      driverOrder: ['indexeddb', 'sqlite', 'websql'],
    })
  ],
  bootstrap: [...],
  entryComponents: [...],
  providers: [...],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

## 2. Inject Storage into your component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  constructor(public storage: Storage) {}
}
```

## 3. Storing data in SQLite

Whenever you access storage, make sure to always wrap your code in the following:

```
storage.ready().then(() => { /* code here safely */});
```

#### 3.1 Saving a key-value pair

```
storage.ready().then(() => {
    storage.set('some key', 'some value');
});
```

#### 3.2 Retrieving a value

```
storage.ready().then(() => {
  storage.get('age').then((val: string) => {
      console.log('Your age is', val);
  });
});
```

#### 3.3 Deleting a key-value pair

```
storage.ready().then(() => {
    storage.remove('key').then((key: string) => { /* do something after deletion */})
});
```