# Ionic Cordova SQLite plugin error Cannot read property 'openDatabase' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I have 1 issue in ngCordova plugin cordovaSQLite. Below code:

```
var db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({ name: "myDB.db" });
```

I'm using `ionic serve` in browser.

Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'openDatabase' of undefinedng-cordova.js:5058 
openDBapp.js:27 
(anonymous function)ionic.bundle.js:37388 
(anonymous function)ionic.bundle.js:2241 
onPlatformReadyionic.bundle.js:2220 
onWindowLoad
```

[image]

Could you please help me?

Comment: What language is this ? Javascript with a variable name starting with $ ?

Comment: @LorenzMeyer: Yes, in JavaScript you can start a variable with $ which is quite common in fact. For example jQuery, MooTools and ng-Cordova use it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As stated by user jonnie in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26102510/1744702)

> Cordova is platform specific and doesn't work when you run ionic serve

and

> you can replace the cordova plugin with window to use the websql databases so instead of sqlitePlugin.openDatabase() you can use window.openDatabase()

It should work on actual devices just fine.

Answer (score 5):

You are getting this error because you are trying to get database connection from android but using wrong function openDatabase(). This function will use in case of client (browser). Use openDb() function to get database connection from android.

```
 if (window.cordova) {
       db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({ name: "my.db" }); //device
            console.log("Android");
     }
     else{
       db = window.openDatabase("my.db", '1', 'my', 1024 * 1024 * 100); // browser
       console.log("browser");
    }
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others

Answer (score 0):

You will not get the desired result if you test in a web browser. You need an actual device, be it an Android or iOS. You can you use [MEMU](http://www.memuplay.com/) or Bluestack emulator to install and check if you don't want an actual device. 
Please don't consider other steps, that's a waste of time.