# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'openDatabase' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, sqlite, ionic-framework, sql-server-2012-localdb

I want to work with sqlite with cordova framework for the first time. As I've read on a tutorial I should use ngcordova like this:

```
  if (window.cordova)
     {
     db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({ name: "littlebird.db" }); //device
     }
    else
     {
            db = window.openDatabase("littlebird.db", '1', 'littlebird', 1024 * 1024 * 100); // browser
     }

        $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mobileContact (id integer primary key, name text, mobile text,exit integer)");
```

but facing issue while deployment

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'openDatabase' of undefined ng-cordova.min.js (9,20659)
```

Comment: I think you have the anwer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27866396/ionic-cordovasqlite-plugin-error-cannot-read-property-opendatabase-of-undefine

Comment: same code but issue still there

Comment: maybe you can try to open an issue directly in the github of ng-cordoba project: https://github.com/driftyco/ng-cordova/issues

Comment: you should definetly read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28244311/typeerror-cannot-read-property-opendatabase-of-undefined :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit :

specifying the location solve the problem :

db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({ name: "DBname.db" ,location:'?'});

(look in the comments of this answers post for more details. )

Comment: db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({ name: "littlebird.db", location: 2, createFromLocation: 1 }); //device

Comment: Great,  Seems specifying the location solve the problem.