# TypeError: Cannot read property 'openDatabase' of undefined

Tags: sqlite, cordova

I want to work with sqlite with cordova framework for the first time. As I've read on a tutorial I should use ngcordova like this:

```
var db = null;
app.controller('mainCtrl', function ($scope, $ionicSideMenuDelegate) {
    $scope.toggleLeft = function () {
        $ionicSideMenuDelegate.toggleLeft();
    }
    $scope.toggleRight = function () {
        $ionicSideMenuDelegate.toggleRight();
    }
})
.controller('home_ctrl', function ($scope, $cordovaSQLite) {
    db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({name: "my.db"});
        //db = $window.opendb({name: "my.db"});
        $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS people(id integer primary key, firstname text, lastname text)")
})
;
```

When I run this code an error says:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'openDatabase' of undefined
```

In some articles like this: [How do I use the ngCordova sqlite service and the Cordova-SQLitePlugin with Ionic Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26101120/how-do-i-use-the-ngcordova-sqlite-service-and-the-cordova-sqliteplugin-with-ioni)
recommends to use commands like this: `ionic start myApp sidemenu`
I don't know what is it, I just use cordova command like: `cordova run android` or `cordova create my_project`
What should I do to run my create a table from my cordova project?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You might take a look at this tutorial:

https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/11/use-sqlite-instead-local-storage-ionic-framework/

When you see this error:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'openDatabase' of undefined`

It is happening for one of a few reasons:

1. You are not wrapping the `$cordovaSQLite` methods in the `$ionicPlatform.ready()` function.
2. You are trying to test this native plugin from a web browser.
3. You have not actually installed the base SQLite plugin into your project.

The most common reasons for this error are #1 and #2.  Native plugins, must be used only after the application is confirmed ready, thus the `$ionicPlatform.ready()` method.  Since native plugins use native code, you cannot test them from your web browser.

Read through the tutorial I linked because it should help you.

Regards,

Comment: thanks, I was trying at web & considering as problem

Comment: so, with typeorm runing like "ionic cordova run browser" the app cannot acces to the local database @Nic Raboy ??

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I opened an old project and I get this error only when I run the project with -cls (because of liverelaod). But I have a small bug to fix there so I didn't investigate it too much(just fix it without livereload). But maybe this little hint helps somebody.

Comment: Hi @fvukovic, did you investigate it now??